# Laravel Share Variables between multiple Controllers

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using the AppServiceProvider to share specific admin data with all related views.

Now I'd like to share admin data also with all admin related Controllers to replace `Auth::guard('admin')->user()->firstname by $admin->firstname`.

```
$id = Auth::guard('admin')->user()->id;
$admin = Admin::findOrFail($id)->first();
```

How can I share this piece of code with all related Controllers to get for example admin `firstname` via `$admin->firstname`?

Comment: What does the `Auth::guard('admin')->user()` returns?, Did you try `Auth::user()->firstname` ?

Answer (score 0):

I would go about creating a global middleware

```
php artisan make:middleware AdminCarrier
```

In the middleware, you can add the `$admin` variable to the `$request` bag and access it via the Controller.

```
class AdminCarrier
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $id = Auth::guard('admin')->user()->id;
        $admin = Admin::findOrFail($id)->first();

        $request->request->add(['admin' => $admin]);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

In the controller, you can access it via:

```
$request->admin
```

Make sure the middleware is global by registering it at `Http/Kernel.php`

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't working for me… I included Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth as well as the Admin Model, but $id = Auth::guard('admin')->user()->id is empty, although I'm logged in.

Comment: What does a `dd(Auth::guard('admin')->user())` says?

Comment: it says null, is there an alternative way to handle my Problem?

Comment: view composer of view->share may help you  https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views#view-composers

Comment: @arety_ then you are not authenticating the user correctly. The guard must be used wrongly